# how to efficiently do large matrix multiplications on Google cloud data flow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We need to multiply a large matrix with a one-dimensional vector. The large matrix is sparse. In  a second scenario, we need to multiply two large matrices, both of which are sparse. And in the third scenario, we need to multiply two large matrices both of which are dense.

Apache Spark seems to provide a built-in data type for matrices (including a specialized one for sparse matrices) as well as what seems to be a very rich set of libraries for matrix linear algebra (multiplication, addition, transposition, etc.)

How can one *efficiently*  do the matrix multiplications (or other linear algebra operations for matrixes) on Google Cloud DataFlow for the three scenarios described above?

Answer (score 3):

Dataflow currently doesn't support matrix operations natively. That said, it should be possible to implement these operations similarly to spark.

For sparse matrices, it should be possible to key by the `(x,y)` coordinate, and then do a `GroupByKey`.

For dense matrices, you can divide the matrix into blocks, use a `GroupByKey` to group the blocks, and then use a native library (such as BLAS) to implement the multiplication on the blocks.

See [BlockMatrix](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/BlockMatrix.scala) for more information on how the block operations are implemented in Spark.

Comment: Are you able to answer this question as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558656/google-cloud-matrix-multiplication-with-bigquery-or-some-other-service)? How to implement matrix multiplication in Google Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

The following [method](http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/datasci/recoded_videos%2F021_map_reduce_matrix_multiply%20%5Babec4802%5D%20.mp4) should work on dataflow.

Comment: Please include the main points of the linked resource in your answer itself, so that people can understand the basic idea without clicking through, and if the link stops working the answer will still be useful.