# Google Cloud: matrix multiplication with Bigquery or some other service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, matrix-multiplication

I am using Google Analytics and processing the data with Bigquery, I need to do a [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

*What is the most feasible way of implementing matrix multiplication in Google Cloud? Can it be done directly in Bigquery?*

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming MatrixA is a table with below columns:

```
i, k, value
```

and MatrixB - has schema as

```
k, j, value
```

and also assuming that range of k-values is the same in both tables:

This would mimic below matrices :

```
Matrix A
 2 -3  4
-1  0  2

Matrix B
-1  2  3
 0  1  7
 1  1 -2
```

Below code for multiplication is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH MatrixA AS (
  SELECT 1 AS i, 1 AS k, 2 AS val UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, -3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, -1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3, 2 
), MatrixB AS (
  SELECT 1 AS k, 1 AS j, -1 AS val UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3, 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 2, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 3, -2 
)
SELECT i, j, SUM(a.val * b.val) val
FROM MatrixA AS a
CROSS JOIN MatrixB AS b
WHERE a.k = b.k
GROUP BY i, j
ORDER BY i, j
```

result will be as below

```
Row i   j   val  
1   1   1   2    
2   1   2   5    
3   1   3   -23  
4   2   1   3    
5   2   2   0    
6   2   3   -7
```

which represents MatrixA * MatrixB

```
2   5  -23
3   0   -7
```

as a note:  you can use

```
FROM MatrixA AS a
JOIN MatrixB AS b
ON a.k = b.k
```

instead of

```
FROM MatrixA AS a
CROSS JOIN MatrixB AS b
WHERE a.k = b.k
```

just matter of your preferences

Comment: Suppose you have matrix `P:=(Path, val)`, its transpose `P^t=(val, Path)` and the matrix multiplication `M:=P P^t`. How would you implement this? You use the cross join and then you use `a.Path=b.Path` for the join?

Comment: Ok I got that +1, how would you reformat the straight table 36x1 into 6x6 format? Is there some ready command for this? I provided the demo below, refactored your example.

Comment: You can see the new question about shaping the straight table of matrix multiplication into more traditional matrix multiplication format [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51560386/bigquery-straight-table-format-of-matrix-multiplication-into-more-traditional-m).

Comment: sorry for asking - but have you tried to do a search here on SO as I recommend? just asking

Comment: It is better to have complete answers, (6x1) (1x6) multiplication should end up to (6x6). Perhaps a separate question on this helps to find the answer on this later for others as well.

Comment: sure. you are the boss of your questions :o)  still, would be great to better understand your use case  - usually it help a lot vs. answering quite generic questions. from my practice in cases like yours (the way I see it ) it is the most practical to have such data in flattened (as you call it - straight - way) so you have extreme flexibility to process data in whatever way you need. whereas pivots are usually good when you want to visualize result - but usually it is to be done in visualizations tool. Btw, recently I answered similar Q and showed how to do so in BigQuery UI with BQ Mate ...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a matrix with two columns, a path and a value column. You want to get the adjacency matrix `P P^t`. With 6 paths, you wanna get 36 values or 6x6 matrix that can be done with matrix multiplication.

I refactor Mikhail example for a path adjacency matrix given some tuple `(Path, value)`. The demo contains 6 paths so the resulting adjacency matrix has dimensions 6x6. It is now in a straight format, but I would like to get it into a matrix formar or crosstab format with 6x6 form.

```
--standardSQL
WITH MatrixA AS (
  SELECT 1 AS p, 2 AS val UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, -3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, -1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 2 
), MatrixB AS (
  SELECT 1 AS p, -1 AS val UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 1
),
matrixMultiplication AS
(
SELECT a.p AS ap, b.p as bp, SUM(a.val * b.val) val
FROM MatrixA AS a
CROSS JOIN MatrixB AS b
GROUP BY a.p, b.p
ORDER BY a.p, b.p
)

--36 elements for the 6x6 PATHS Matrix
--TODO: how to shape it to 6x6 matrix?
SELECT * FROM matrixMultiplication
```

where the shaping question is now [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51560386/bigquery-straight-table-format-of-matrix-multiplication-into-more-traditional-m) about shaping the straight table into more traditional matrix multiplication format.